# CoreData save not work in `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview, core-data

I have met a problem on `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `save` method of CoreData. First is that I created a new model version to add a new field of `Integer 16`. And I need to display this field in a table view. Since the old model version does not contain this field, the initial value is `NULL` in the database. In the `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I get the `NSManagedObject` from my data source fetched by `NSFetchedResultController`. I first check that field value. If it is `NULL`, I will create one, and perform `setValue:forKey:` to the `NSManagedObject` to update the record, and save the context to the database. However, the value is not saved when I open the `.sqlite` file. So I wonder why the value is not saved.

By the way, I am doing iOS development.

Thank you.

Comment: Stupid question:  What is the directory that contains your .sqlite file??  If you're trying to access it in the bundle, that's read-only.

Comment: I have successfully created the object and write the initial information to the database. When I want to update some information, the save method does nothing. @Hot Licks

Comment: Saving changes in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is an incredibly bad idea. Even if you fix your code so it works, the performance will be ridiculously bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is not enough to fully understand the problem. Please share some sample code, specially how you're setting up core-data.

1. Is .sqlite file in your application bundle? If it is, then note that it's readonly.
2. If you want to update your existing database, then `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not the right place to do that. You should do that after your application launches (only once).

p.s. I'm assuming that you have the basic understanding of core-data (NSManagedObjectContext and NSFetchedResultsController).

Comment: Yes, finally I do that after my application launches. Thank you.